# How to set bar widths independent of ticks in matplotlib?

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, spacing

I'm working on a cascade chart (something in [this style](http://www.add-ins.com/images/cascade-chart-of-profit.png)) using matplotlib. I'd like to get all of my bars of varying widths flush with each other, but I'd like the ticks at the bottom to increase regularly from 1 to 7, independent of the bars. However, at the moment, it looks like this:

[image: Barchart with irregularly spaced bars]

So far this is what I've got:

```
python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter


n_groups = 6
name=['North America','Russia','Central & South America','China','Africa','India'] 

joules = [33.3, 21.8, 4.22, 9.04, 1.86, 2.14]
popn=[346,143,396,1347,1072,1241]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = [0.346,.143,.396,1.34,1.07,1.24]

opacity = 0.4

rects1 = plt.bar(index+bar_width, joules, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='b',
                 label='Countries')

def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for ii,rect in enumerate(rects):
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height, '%s'%(name[ii]),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.xlabel('Population (millions)')
plt.ylabel('Joules/Capita (ten billions)')
plt.title('TPEC, World, 2012')
plt.xticks(1, ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6')
autolabel(rects1)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

And all the variations I've tried so far to adjust the bar spacing have resulted in similar issues. Any ideas?

Comment: get rid of the ticks and just use `text` or `annotate` to add the labels in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment the problem is that your `index` is a regular sequence, so the left hand edges of each bar are positioned at regular intervals. What you want is for `index` to be a running total of the bar x-values, so that the left hand edge of each bar lines up with the right hand edge of the previous one.

You can do this using `np.cumsum()`:

```
...
index = np.cumsum(bar_width)
...
```

Now `index` will start at `bar_width[0]`, so you'll need to set the left hand edge of the bars to `index - bar_width`:

```
rects1 = plt.bar(index-bar_width, ...)
```

Result:

[image]

You'll of course want to play around with the axis limits and label positions to make it look nice.

Comment: you can also use `align='center'`