# Get rid of the spaces histogram matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have to build a histogram. For example, with an interval of 25 - 34 on the y axis, there should be 7 and so on. I made a decision, but I need to get rid of the spaces to the right of each column.[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qKLv.png) Code: https://repl.it/repls/PhonyMonumentalChief Unfortunately, I did not find a solution to this problem. I will be glad to any help!

Comment: Surprisingly, I can't find an exact duplicate on SO. But there are [numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44340637/how-to-fix-bar-width-in-this-matplotlib-plot) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46175808/python-matplotlib-bars-overlapping-although-width-1) relating to setting the [width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254852/how-to-set-bar-widths-independent-of-ticks-in-matplotlib) of a bar in matplotlib. Use the `width` parameter of `ax.bar()`.

Comment: @bnaecker I found a duplicate.

Comment: @bnaecker Thank you so much!